# Is there a way to match acronyms with their extended names in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, acronym

I'm indexing people's tweets and their location using Lucene, but people put so weird names as location...however...

Is there a way to match these (in indexing time or in query time)?
1) USA
2) United States of America
3) United States

1) Oklahoma
2) Ok

and so on...

P.S. I'd like a solution thanks to which I don't need to write a synonim dictionary on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address this both at indexing or at querying time.

At indexing time you would need to enrich your data by doing a lookup in a synonym dictionary you provide and then index both, the original term and the synonym with the same postings information.

Alternatively you can do the same look with the query string and build up a BooleanQuery "OR"-ing the original term and the synonym.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like a solution in which I don't need to write the synonims dictionary on my own

Comment: Often search engines come with support for synonym dictionaries, but still you would need to provide the dictionaries. AFAIK, there is no ootb solution for your need.

Comment: How to index two terms with the same postings information? Do I have to create a new TextField, with the same name? Maybe I'll try to solve it at query time, because it's not very clear to me that. If you have any example, please put here a link

Comment: You would probably need to define your own Lucene Analyser with a custom filter doing the lookups and ejecting both, the acronym and the extended version. You then could use the the same analyser also at query time. But this approach requires re-indexing all the tweets once you change a mapping/synonym.

In your case you might want doing it at query time as you are doing now.

Comment: Just another question: I can't understand from the documentation what StandardFilter exactly does: "Normalizes tokens extracted with StandardTokenizer.". What does the documentation mean with "normalizes"?

Comment: Analysis is a fundamental concept of Lucene, relevant at indexing at querying time. I would recommend that you get a copy of "Lucene in Action" or study an online resource to understand that concept. SOLR and ELasticSearch all build on the same concept from Lucene. A light-weight introduction might be the video [Understanding Lucene Analyzers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9bgz8_bM20)